# Partition Triangle

Tags: diagrams, plot, graphs, coordinates, nodes-near-coords

I am working on a paper on integer partitions and I want to add something like this. This is not my picture, it is from another paper, but is it possible to do this on LaTex? I want to be able to customize the amount of points and the labels on the points. Any help would be appreciated[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE! If you've not done so yet, have a look at pgf and Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Anything you can imagine is possible to draw in latex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know exactly what kind of changes you will need, but perhaps this could be a starting point. My approach is basically to use `calc` library to compute the coordinates of the dots.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {amsmath} % for pmatrix
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    % for coordinates

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-0.4cm,-0.3cm)},y={(1cm,0cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)},%
                    line cap=round,line join=round]
  % coordinates
  \def\a{2}
  \def\b{4}
  \def\c{4}
  \coordinate (A) at (\a,0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (0,\b,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (0,0,\c);
  \coordinate (M) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
  \coordinate (G) at ($(C)!{2/3}!(M)$);
  \foreach\i in {1,...,6}
  {% dots in olive and red lines
    \coordinate (A\i) at ($(A)!{\i/6}!(G)$);
    \coordinate (C\i) at ($(M)!{\i/6}!(G)$);
  }
  % axes
  \draw (0,0,0) -- (\a+1,0,0);
  \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,\b+1,0);
  \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\c+1);
  % other lines
  \draw[thick,olive] (A) -- ($(B)!0.5!(C)$);
  \draw[thick,gray]  (B) -- ($(A)!0.5!(C)$);
  \draw[thick,red]   (C) -- ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
  \draw[thick,dashed,cyan]  (A) -- (B);
  \draw[thick]       (A) -- (C) -- (B);
  % dots
  \fill (G) circle (2pt);
  \foreach\i in {1,...,5}
  {% 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\np{18-3*\i}
    \foreach\j in {0,2,...,\np}
    {%
      \fill ($(A\i)!{\j/\np}!(C\i)$) circle (2pt);
    }
  }
  % labels
  \draw (G)  circle (3pt) --++ (2cm,3cm)
        node[right] {\small$\begin{pmatrix}6\\6\\6\end{pmatrix}$};
  \draw (A1) circle (3pt) --++ (-1cm,1cm)
        node[left]  {\small$\begin{pmatrix}16\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$};
  \draw ($(A3)!{8/9}!(C3)$) circle (3pt) --++ (2cm,1cm)
        node[right] {\small$\begin{pmatrix}8\\7\\3\end{pmatrix}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's just what I wanted!

Comment: Hello again, how would I add an extra line of dots under the very last row?

Comment: @Lewis, you only have to change the lines `\foreach\i in {1,...,6}` to `\foreach\i in {0,...,6}` and `\foreach\i in {1,...,5}` to `\foreach\i in {0,...,5}`. This sets how many lines of dots there are, and their heights.

Answer (score 4):

A reasonable choice for `3D` graphics would be `Asymptote`:

```
// file  diag.asy
// 
// run 
//     asy diag.asy
// to get a standalone image  diag.pdf
// 
settings.tex="pdflatex";
import graph3; size(200,0);
currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(67,9,14));
import fontsize; defaultpen(fontsize(7pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}\usepackage{amsmath}"
  +"\usepackage{amsfonts}\usepackage{amssymb}");
triple A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,K,L; real r=0.3;
A=( 6,6,6); B=(18,0, 0); C=(9, 9,0);
D=( 8,0,3); E=( 0,0,18); F=(0,18,0);
G=( 0,9,9); H=( 9,0, 9); K=(16,1,1); L=( 8,7, 3);
void drop(guide3[] g, pen[] p){
  for(int i=0;i<g.length;++i) draw(project(g[i]),p[i]);
}
guide3[] line={B--E--F--cycle, B--G, E--C, F--H, 
A--E--B, O--20*Y, O--22*X, O--20*Z,};
pen[] p={darkblue,deepgreen,red,blue,}; p.cyclic=true;
drop(line,p);
for(int i=0;i<7;++i){
  for(int j=0;j<=9-i-ceil(i/2);++j){
    dot(project(B+i*(-2,1,1)+j*(-1,1,0)),UnFill);
  }
}
void labLoc(triple V, triple P){
  pair v=project(V), p=project(P);
  draw(circle(v,r)); draw((v+r*dir(p-v))--p);
  label("$\begin{pmatrix}"+string(V.x)+"\\"+string(V.y)
    +"\\"+string(V.z)+"\end{pmatrix}$",p,dir(p-v));
}
labLoc(A,(0,8,12));labLoc(K,(16,-2,4));labLoc(L,(0,12,9));
```

[image]

Comment: +1 surely. Please, have you seen this question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596306/error-when-calling-pdfcrop-from-within-asy-input-file

Comment: @Sebastiano: I have, but it looks like 
`pdfcrop` solves it nicely, and it becomes more like 
a simple automation question, which can be solved 
by many means like e.g. catch files or just running asy twice.
Of course, if the developers of the Asymptote can solve it
that would be nice, but I don't think that efforts 
of reimplementing already existent functionality
worth it, unless perhaps, if they know that if can be done easily 
by just a couples of code lines.

Comment: I thank you infinitely for your comprehensive explanation that I understood without using the translator. I thought it was a specific question for you and I know you are very good with Asymptote. I always wish you the best.