# Error when calling pdfcrop from within asy input file

Tags: asymptote

This question is a follow of the [Crop all pdf file pictures created with asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596126/crop-all-pdf-file-pictures-created-with-asymptote) (the title has been redited) and the AlexG suggestion of using `pdfcrop`.

Since my asy files are edited and compiled with emacs and to avoid a lot of come and go between emacs and the shell terminal I try to call `pdfcrop` directly from within the asy input file by using the asymptote function `system("pdfcrop example.pdf example.pdf")`

```
   // asymptote file test.asy
   unitsize(cm);
   path p1=unitsquare;
   path p2=circle((-5,0),1);
   draw(scale(1,5)*p1);
   newpage();
   draw(p2);
   shipout();
   system("pdfcrop test.pdf test.pdf");
   // end of test.asy
```

Although the output file is well located in the directory at the end of the compilation I get the error:

```
  PDFCROP 1.40, 2020/06/06 - Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Heiko Oberdiek, Oberdiek Package Support Group.
    !!! Error: Input file `test.pdf' not found!
```

Could it be that the output file "test.pdf" is only created  after all the commands in the asy input file are called (despite the fact that the `shipout` command is located before the `system` command) so the "test.pdf" file is not yet created when `pdfcrop` is called ?

How could we force the `system` command to be executed after the output file is created?

Comment: Could the OS need some time delay to create and write the file?

Comment: @HerbSchulz I have tried a dely of up to 20 s but no resullts

Comment: I vote positive your question and your effort.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastiano that's very encouraging ;)